# How can I use PowerShell's -filter parameter to exclude values/files?

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm currently running a PowerShell (v3.0) script, one step of which is to retrieve all the HTML files in a directory. That works great:

`$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $srcPath -filter "*.htm*"`

However, now I'm faced with having to identify all the non-HTML files...CSS, Word and Excel docs, pictures, etc.

I want something that would work like the `-ne` parameter in conjunction with the `-filter` parameter. In essence, give me everything that's **not** `"*.htm*"`

`-filter -ne` doesn't work, I tried `-!filter` on a whim, and I can't seem to find anything in powershell doc on MSDN to *negate* the `-filter` parameter. Perhaps I need to pipe something...?

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-Filter` is not the right way. Use the `-exclude` parameter instead:

```
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $srcPath -exclude *.htm*
```

`-exclude` accepts a `string[]` type as an input. In that way you can exclude more than one extension/file type as follows:

```
 $srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $srcPath -exclude *.htm*,*.css,*.doc*,*.xls*
```

..And so on.

Comment: yea.. with a small warning that adding -exclude can actually **change your output structure**. I've had `Get-ChildItem -Path "*.Tests" -Directory` to grab all directories ending with 'Tests', and it behaved as expected: returned 1 group with few items being xx.Tests directories themselves.. When I added `-Exclude 'Common.*'`, then instead of excluding "Common.Tests", it did something strange like returning few groups with contents of xxx.Tests directories inside each..

Answer (score 6):

I am a little newer to PowerShell, but could you pipe to the where command?

```
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $srcPath | where-object {$_.extension -ne "*.htm*"}
```

I am not sure what the actually property you would use in place "extension" is though.

Comment: Are you sure that globbing works in `-ne`? I just tried filtering directories with `$_.Name -ne 'Common.*'` and it totally did not work. It worked only when I passed full name like `$_.Name -ne 'Common.Tests'`