# How to copy local files AND PATHS to network share using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Using PowerShell, I'm trying to pipe a file list from my local drive so Copy-Items can copy them to a network folder.  The following statement does find the files I need, and copies them.  However, all path information is lost and they all end up in the same folder.  I want each file to be saved in relative path fashion at the destination with its file path from the local disk.

So for example "c:\users\user_name\Documents\file_1.txt" should be copied to "\\server\share\my_folder\users\user_name\Documents\file_1.txt"

My searches have proved fruitless.  Can this statement be modified to achieve that?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users\user_name -r | ? {!($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date} | %{Copy-Item -Path $_.fullname -destination "\\server\share\my_folder" -Recurse -Force -Container}
```

EDIT:

It seems like Copy-Item should be able to do this.  The following command works:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\users\user_name\Documents -Destination "\\server\share\my_folder" -recurse -Force
```

This command copies all files, sub-folders and files in the sub-folders found in and under c:\users\user_name\Documents.  It then recreates the relative directory structure on the network share.  It seems like the $_.fullname parameter from the first command is not being treated in a similar fashion.  I'm most certainly not piping file list in the expected manner to Copy-Item.  Any other advice?

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at `robocopy` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get relative path of files in sub-folders from the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972589/get-relative-path-of-files-in-sub-folders-from-the-current-directory)

Comment: @iRon - That does not answer my question.  I have the relative path info, I'm trying to recreate that structure on the network file share.  Below Doug Maurer indicates there is no way for the Copy-Item command to accomplish that.  So, I guess I have to roll my own functionality that was present in MS-DOS 6.0.  Disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was quite the challenge, but I finally found a mechanism.  Thanks to @iRob for pointing me to a potential solution.  I could not get his code to create the relative paths at the destination, but was able to extend his concept.  I ended up adding in a New-Item command (found via [Powershell 2 copy-item which creates a folder if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695504/powershell-2-copy-item-which-creates-a-folder-if-doesnt-exist)) and a Split-Path (found here [Copy a list of files to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712435/copy-a-list-of-files-to-a-directory)).  The Split-Path sliced off the file name from the joined path, then that path was created via the New-Item command.  Finally the Copy-Item had a place to copy the file.  So in that sense @Doug Maurer was also right that Copy-Item would not do this itself.  Some extra preparation was need before the Copy-Item command could successfully run.

```
Set-Location c:\users\user_name; Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date } | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname -destination (New-Item -type directory -force ((Join-Path '\\server\share\my_folder' ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative)) | Split-Path -Parent)) -Force}
```

IMHO something that was trivial in MS-DOS 6.0 (xcopy /D:08-20-2020 /S c:\users\user_name*.* \server\share\my_folder) should not be so difficult in PowerShell.  Seems like there should be an easier way.  Now that I think of it, probably should have stuck to xcopy instead of diving down this rabbit hole.  PowerShell just seems so shiny.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things we should go over. First, If you just want files you can drop the !$_.psiscontainer check and just add `-file` to the `Get-Childitem` command. Next, if you intend to copy files that are older that `Get-Date`, the comparison needs to be `-lt`. As for creating the directory structure in the destination, you'd need to make it yourself. You can achieve it by stripping `c:` off the path and using the `*-Path` cmdlets like this.

```
$source      = 'c:\users\user_name\Documents'
$destination = '\\server\share\my_folder'

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).date} |
        ForEach-Object {
            $destdir = Join-Path $destination (Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent).Substring(2)
            
            If(-not(Test-Path $destdir))
            {
                Write-Host Making directory $destdir -ForegroundColor Cyan
                $null = New-Item -Path $destdir -ItemType Directory
            }
            
            Write-Host Copying file $_.name to $destdir -ForegroundColor Green
            Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destdir
        }
```

However as Bill_Stewart said `robocopy` or another tool may be a better fit. `Robocopy` would surely be much faster so if you need this to process a lot of data, I'd direct my effort in that direction.

Comment: No, I don't want files older than Get-Date.  What about my question suggested that my boolean comparison was opposite of what I wrote?  My question indicated that I was returning the files I was after AND copying them.  They were just not being copied as I had hoped.  I included !$_.psiscontainer since I'm trying to copy files and folders.  So, taking the implication of your re-worked question and Bill_Stewart's comment from above, the answer to my question appears to be "No".  The Copy-Item portion of my statement can't be reworked to re-create the file paths.

Comment: So you want files made in the future that don’t exist yet. Also, !$_.psiscontainer means not a directory so you’re filtering those out.

Comment: 1) This will be run at the end of the day and pick up files that were created/updated the same day.  I'm trying to create an incremental back-up strategy.  As I say, I'm finding the files I need.  2) Not a directory - I don't want to pipe an updated directory to Copy-Item since that will result in a full directory copy.  This command works in that it lists the files I want to copy: Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users\tlash -r | ? {!($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date}.  I just can't get the path to copy.

Comment: I do believe you’re correct about copy item. If you were doing a folder recursively it would create the sub directories, but for each file I don’t know of a way other than what I’ve suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the noted using [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7) (see: [Get relative path of files in sub-folders from the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10974709/1701026)):

```
Set-Location c:\users\user_name
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date } |
    Foreach-Object {
        $Destination = Join-Path \\server\share\my_folder ("$_" | Resolve-Path -Relative)
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $destination -Force
        Copy-Item -Path "$_" -Destination $Destination -Force
    }
```

Comment: that one-liner did not work.  It does return a proper file list, but the Copy-Item component still fails: "ObjectNotFound: (c:\users\user_name\test.txt:string) [Resilve-Path], ItemNotFoundException.  test.txt is in Documents.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to remove the last `-Recurse` and `-Container` switches as that is already defined by the `Get-ChildItem`  and `Where-Object` cmdlets (I have update the answer).

Comment: Same error.  When I use this == Set-Location c:\users\user_name; Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date } | Resolve-Path -Relative == I get: .\Documents\test.txt.  However, the Copy-Item is still trying to copy c:\users\user_name\test.txt which does not exist.  Copy-Items can't be made to recognize the path being passed.

Comment: Okay, this works - Set-Location c:\users\user_name; Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -AND $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).date } | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname -destination (Join-Path '\\server\share\my_folder' ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative)) -Force }                                         BUT ONLY IF THE DESTINATION FOLDER "Documents" ALREADY EXISTS.  So close!

Comment: This "folder" issue is in fact described at [Should Copy-Item create the destination directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523632/1701026). I incorporated this in the answer. I did removed the oneliner as is no longer clear what it does but you might simply concatenate the statements with a semicolon (`;`) if you do need a one liner (you can also just paste multiple lines into your IDE).