# Copy items that contain the name of the folder

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, get-childitem, copy-item

I need a script for windows to copy some files that contain a reference to a folder that has the name of the reference in their name.

Example: The file `K:\examplefolder\sourcefolder\example3456file.pdf` go to the folder `K:\examplefolder\Destfolder\3456`.

I created this:

```
$Src =  'K:\Escritorio\Scripts\Script_copiar_planos\Script OT\Origen'
$Dst = 'K:\Escritorio\Scripts\Script_copiar_planos\Script OT\Destino'
$file = 'K:\Escritorio\Scripts\Script_copiar_planos\Script OT\referencias.txt'

foreach ($referencia in Get-Content $file){
  Get-ChildItem  -Path $Src -Recurse -include *$referencia*.pdf -name -file | Copy-item -Destination $Dst\$referencia 
}
```

In `referencias.txt` the references are listed like:

```
5678
91011
121314
```

For me apparently is okay, but when I go to execute the script it drops the following errors:

```
Copy-item : No se encuentra la ruta de acceso 'K:\Escritorio\Scripts\PDF-Con-81006600-en-el-nombre - copia (2).pdf' porque no existe.
En K:\Escritorio\Scripts\Script_copiar_planos\mover.ps1: 11 Carácter: 81
+ ... referencia*.pdf -name -file | Copy-item -Destination $Dst\$referencia
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (K:\Escritorio\S...- copia (2).pdf:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy local files AND PATHS to network share using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476891/how-to-copy-local-files-and-paths-to-network-share-using-powershell)

Comment: Is it a share? You have to specify the full UNC path instead of the drive letter. Instead of `K:\``, use the dns name and/or, IP, `\\shared\drive`

Comment: iRon: it help me in a half, with this i can copy items in the main folder but no in the sob-folders

Abraham: is in local machine

Comment: no entiendo lo que estas trantando de hacer.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - this part of SO is for english language stuff. please use that language so that folks here can understand what you are posting. there is a spanish part of SO ... Stack Overflow en español — https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @zett42 You are right, thx

How can put your answer as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass argument `-name` to `Get-ChildItem`, it outputs only the file name portion of the path, e. g. "file1.pdf". This way `Copy-Item` has no information about the folder of the file and will use the [working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.1), whatever that happens to be before the call to `Get-ChildItem`.

Remove the argument `-name` to pass the full source path to `Copy-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Path $Src -Recurse -include *$referencia*.pdf -file | Copy-item -Destination $Dst\$referencia
```

As a further optimization, you could replace `-include` by `-filter`, which is more efficient. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#parameters):

> Filters are more efficient than other parameters. The provider applies
> filter when the cmdlet gets the objects rather than having PowerShell
> filter the objects after they're retrieved.